# How can I convert a string to a dataframe, specifying the number of columns?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a string that looks as follow:

```
string = "entity precision recall f1-score support B-EXPERIENCE 0.578 0.488 0.529 244 I-EXPERIENCE 0.648 0.799 0.716 399 L-EXPERIENCE 0.850 0.697 0.766 244 U-EXPERIENCE 0.000 0.000 0.000 9 B-LANGUAGE 0.000 0.000 0.000 1 I-LANGUAGE 0.000 0.000 0.000 1 L-LANGUAGE 0.000 0.000 0.000 1 U-LANGUAGE 0.788 0.904 0.842 292 B-PROGRAMMING 0.480 0.433 0.455 141 I-PROGRAMMING 0.524 0.328 0.404 67 L-PROGRAMMING 0.261 0.255 0.258 141 U-PROGRAMMING 0.904 0.825 0.862 2010 micro_avg 0.785 0.746 0.765 3550 macro_avg 0.419 0.394 0.403 3550 weighted_avg 0.787 0.746 0.763 3550"
```

What is the simplest way to convert this into a pandas dataframe with the following format? I am looking to create a dataframe with 5 columns, the header for the first column can be filled with "entity". The first column contains the names of the entities.

[image]

Comment: 5 or 4 columns? I see 4 in your example

Comment: 5 columns. I edited the description slightly.

Comment: Can you change the inputs of that string such that "macro avg" becomes "macro_avg"  Replacing those spaces in the row index with underscores?

Comment: Or, is your seperator between values tabs instead of spaces?

Comment: I changed the input like you asked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use numpy reshape:

```
data = np.array(string.split())
data = data.reshape(len(data)//5, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]).set_index('entity').rename_axis('')
print(df)
```

gives:

```
              precision recall f1-score support

B-EXPERIENCE      0.578  0.488    0.529     244
I-EXPERIENCE      0.648  0.799    0.716     399
L-EXPERIENCE      0.850  0.697    0.766     244
U-EXPERIENCE      0.000  0.000    0.000       9
B-LANGUAGE        0.000  0.000    0.000       1
I-LANGUAGE        0.000  0.000    0.000       1
L-LANGUAGE        0.000  0.000    0.000       1
U-LANGUAGE        0.788  0.904    0.842     292
B-PROGRAMMING     0.480  0.433    0.455     141
I-PROGRAMMING     0.524  0.328    0.404      67
L-PROGRAMMING     0.261  0.255    0.258     141
U-PROGRAMMING     0.904  0.825    0.862    2010
micro_avg         0.785  0.746    0.765    3550
macro_avg         0.419  0.394    0.403    3550
weighted_avg      0.787  0.746    0.763    3550
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the most useful as I actually did prefer the blank space.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = "entity precision recall f1-score support B-EXPERIENCE 0.578 0.488 0.529 244 I-EXPERIENCE 0.648 0.799 0.716 399 L-EXPERIENCE 0.850 0.697 0.766 244 U-EXPERIENCE 0.000 0.000 0.000 9 B-LANGUAGE 0.000 0.000 0.000 1 I-LANGUAGE 0.000 0.000 0.000 1 L-LANGUAGE 0.000 0.000 0.000 1 U-LANGUAGE 0.788 0.904 0.842 292 B-PROGRAMMING 0.480 0.433 0.455 141 I-PROGRAMMING 0.524 0.328 0.404 67 L-PROGRAMMING 0.261 0.255 0.258 141 U-PROGRAMMING 0.904 0.825 0.862 2010 micro_avg 0.785 0.746 0.765 3550 macro_avg 0.419 0.394 0.403 3550 weighted_avg 0.787 0.746 0.763 3550"

s = pd.Series(s1.split(' '))
df = pd.DataFrame(s[5:].to_numpy().reshape(-1,5), columns=s[:5])
```

Output:

```
           entity precision recall f1-score support
0    B-EXPERIENCE     0.578  0.488    0.529     244
1    I-EXPERIENCE     0.648  0.799    0.716     399
2    L-EXPERIENCE     0.850  0.697    0.766     244
3    U-EXPERIENCE     0.000  0.000    0.000       9
4      B-LANGUAGE     0.000  0.000    0.000       1
5      I-LANGUAGE     0.000  0.000    0.000       1
6      L-LANGUAGE     0.000  0.000    0.000       1
7      U-LANGUAGE     0.788  0.904    0.842     292
8   B-PROGRAMMING     0.480  0.433    0.455     141
9   I-PROGRAMMING     0.524  0.328    0.404      67
10  L-PROGRAMMING     0.261  0.255    0.258     141
11  U-PROGRAMMING     0.904  0.825    0.862    2010
12      micro_avg     0.785  0.746    0.765    3550
13      macro_avg     0.419  0.394    0.403    3550
14   weighted_avg     0.787  0.746    0.763    3550
```

Details:

Use `split` to break the string up using space as a delimiter, hence the request in changing the column header naming to remove spaces from column headers.

Create a pd.Series using constructor and then create a pd.DataFrame using constructor and index slicing.   `to_numpy` to create a numpy array, then `reshape` the array using -1 for number of rows, 5 for the number of columns.

Comment: Great happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

If you would adjust the string in the last three entries and remove the white spaces (e.g. replace by dash), the following code would work and can also be extended to more rows:

```
my_list = string.split(' ') # split the string along the whitespaces

my_dict = {}
num_cols = 5
# convert the string to a dictionary with appropriate keys
for i in range(0,num_cols):
    my_dict.update({my_list[i]:my_list[num_cols+i::num_cols]})

# Convert dict to pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

```
>> pd.DataFrame(df)
           entity precision recall f1-score support
0    B-EXPERIENCE     0.578  0.488    0.529     244
1    I-EXPERIENCE     0.648  0.799    0.716     399
2    L-EXPERIENCE     0.850  0.697    0.766     244
3    U-EXPERIENCE     0.000  0.000    0.000       9
4      B-LANGUAGE     0.000  0.000    0.000       1
5      I-LANGUAGE     0.000  0.000    0.000       1
6      L-LANGUAGE     0.000  0.000    0.000       1
7      U-LANGUAGE     0.788  0.904    0.842     292
8   B-PROGRAMMING     0.480  0.433    0.455     141
9   I-PROGRAMMING     0.524  0.328    0.404      67
10  L-PROGRAMMING     0.261  0.255    0.258     141
11  U-PROGRAMMING     0.904  0.825    0.862    2010
12      micro-avg     0.785  0.746    0.765    3550
13      macro-avg     0.419  0.394    0.403    3550
14   weighted-avg     0.787  0.746    0.763    3550
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to divide your string into evenly lists of 5 with `yield` which comes back to the state it left of in the last iteration:

```
cols = string.split()[:5]
vals = string.split()[5:]

# Define function to make evenly chunks of your words
def divide_chunks(l, n): 

    for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

Now we can define our dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(divide_chunks(vals, 5)), columns=cols)
```

Output:

```
           entity precision recall f1-score support
0    B-EXPERIENCE     0.578  0.488    0.529     244
1    I-EXPERIENCE     0.648  0.799    0.716     399
2    L-EXPERIENCE     0.850  0.697    0.766     244
3    U-EXPERIENCE     0.000  0.000    0.000       9
4      B-LANGUAGE     0.000  0.000    0.000       1
5      I-LANGUAGE     0.000  0.000    0.000       1
6      L-LANGUAGE     0.000  0.000    0.000       1
7      U-LANGUAGE     0.788  0.904    0.842     292
8   B-PROGRAMMING     0.480  0.433    0.455     141
9   I-PROGRAMMING     0.524  0.328    0.404      67
10  L-PROGRAMMING     0.261  0.255    0.258     141
11  U-PROGRAMMING     0.904  0.825    0.862    2010
12      micro_avg     0.785  0.746    0.765    3550
13      macro_avg     0.419  0.394    0.403    3550
14   weighted_avg     0.787  0.746    0.763    3550
```